# dynamic combobox in django admin

Tags: django, combobox, admin

I'm having the following problem, I have five classes: Continent, Country,
State, City and Customer, the Customer class would like a list of
countries would be charged based on the selected continent, as well as
states according to the selected country, and the cities according
with the selected state. All this in ADMIN. I would like to help a
as an example.

```
# models.py:

class Continent(models.Model):
    name_co = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='continent')

class Country(models.Model):
    name_cy = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=u'country')
    continent_cy = models.ForeignKey(Continent, verbose_name=u'continent')

class State(models.Model):
    name_st = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'state')
    country_st = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=u'country')

class City(models.Model): 
    name_ci = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'city')
    state_ci = models.ForeignKey(State, verbose_name=u'state') 

class Customer(models.Model):
    name_cu = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'name')   
    continent_cu = models.ForeignKey(Continent, verbose_name='continent') 
    country_cu = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=u'country') 
    state_cu = models.ForeignKey(State, verbose_name=u'state') 
    city_cu = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name=u'city')
```

Answer (score 4):

[Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) will most likely do that for you. From the README:

If you have the following model:

```
class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

And you want that all countries are grouped by the Continent and that Groups are used in the select change to the following:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import GroupedForeignKey

class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = GroupedForeignKey(Country, "continent")
```

Comment: I've tried to use django-smart-select, and even had a few bugs in the way Inline django admin change. Would you like an example using Jquery / Ajax. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Django Smart Selects does exactly what you want to do. I'd check out the its source code for examples. Exactly what problems do you run into using Django Smart Selects?

Comment: Time to load the JQuery Inline mode (and TabularInline
StackedInline), operating in the options only "extra" set. example:
"Extra = 2", runs 1 and 2 in the register, but not if I
add a new account.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to achieve this directly with Django. Try with AJAX and jQuery.